# How can I modify pasted text?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to intercept and modify text that gets pasted into a textarea?

If intercepting isn't possible, can I modify it after being pasted? (Without modifying the already present text in the textarea.)

Comment: Are you using any javascript library (such as jQuery)?

Comment: @Adrian: My question is more about if it's even possible, therefore you can assume any library you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
    jQuery(function($){
      $('#your_element').bind('paste', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        console.log(clipboardData);
      }); 
     }      
    });
```

Works in IE and Webkit. With Firefox you might have to use this:

http://intridea.com/2007/12/16/faking-onpaste-in-firefox?blog=company

Comment: Actually the onpaste event worked in Gecko 1.9.0.19 (Camino 2.0.4). I think it has been introduced in Firefox 3, here's the mozilla page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste There is, however, no good way to get the pasted data.

Comment: Ah, thanks didn't know that Firefox 3 implemented onpaste, but it sucks that you can't get to the data with it.

Comment: And where is information about **modyfing** the data?

Comment: This is not answer to asked question. This is correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438665/how-to-modify-pasted-data-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe intercept `keypress`es, to know when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, cache current text, then at <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'s `keyup`, check current value against cached one, with simple text processing you can know the new text, and do whatever you want with, and update accordingly.

Comment: I'm not certain this works with all browsers, but is definitely a better approach I think. http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of how to do this is to wait for the content to the text field to be pasted then wait for a keyup or a keydown trigger. This is shown in the code below:

```
<script language="javascript">

function testfunction()
{

 // This function will execute whenever the content of 

}
</script>

<textarea onkeyup="testfunction()" onkeydown="testfunction()"></textarea>
```

If you want to monitor a textarea for any changes, the following code would do that. It checks the value of the textarea every 1/10th of a second for any updates.

```
<textarea id="testfield"></textarea>

<script language="javascript">

var textarea = document.getElementById('testfield');
var textval = '';

function monitor()
{

 if(textval != textarea.value)
 {

  textval = textarea.value;
  testfunction();

 }

 setTimeout('monitor()', 100);

}

function testfunction()
{

 // This function will get executed whenever the value of the text area is altered (at most within 1/10th of a second)

}

monitor();
</script>
```

In both cases, you can modify the value of the textarea when testfunction() then update the value of the textarea with the updated value.

Comment: Consider using "setTimeout(monitor, 100);" instead of "setTimeout('monitor()', 100);". Eval is evil :)

Answer (score 0):

You prevent the default paste of the browser using `event.preventDefault();`.

Then you read the clipboard data.

Then you modify the clipboard data and paste it yourself setting the textarea (or input) value.

```
    <textarea id="myTextarea" placeholder="Paste text here..."></textarea>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('myTextarea').addEventListener('paste', function (event) 
        {
            // Prevent the default paste behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get the clipboard data
            const clipboardData = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData);
            let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

            // Modify the pasted text as needed
            // Example: Convert to uppercase
            pastedText = pastedText.toUpperCase(); 

            // Insert the modified text into the textarea
            let textarea = event.target;
            let currentText = textarea.value;
            let selectionStart = textarea.selectionStart;
            let selectionEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;

            const newText = currentText.slice(0, selectionStart) + pastedText + currentText.slice(selectionEnd);

            textarea.value = newText;
        });
    </script>
```