# What's the meaning of "()" in a function call?

Tags: javascript

Now, I usually call a function (that requires no arguments) with `()` like this:

```
myFunction(); //there's empty parens
```

Except in jQuery calls where I can get away with:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', myFunction); //no parens
```

Fine. But recently I saw this comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640187/how-can-i-modify-pasted-text) on SO:

"Consider using `setTimeout(monitor, 100);` instead of `setTimeout('monitor()', 100);`. Eval is evil :)"

Yikes! Are we really `eval()`-ing a string here? I guess I don't really understand the significance and implications of 'calling' a function. What are the real rules about calling and referring to functions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In JavaScript functions are first-class objects. That means you can pass functions around as parameters to a function, or treat them as variables in general.

Let's say we are talking about a function `hello`,

```
function hello() {
    alert('yo');
}
```

When we simply write

```
hello
```

we are referring to the function which doesn't execute it's contents. But when we add the parens `()` after the function name,

```
hello()
```

then we are actually calling the function which will alert "yo" on the screen.

The `bind` method in jQuery accepts the type of event (string) and a function as its arguments. In your example, you are passing the type - "click" and the actual function as an argument.

Have you seen Inception? Consider this contrived example which might make things clearer. Since functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, we can pass and return a function from within a function. So let's create a function that returns a function when invoked, and the returned function also returns another function when invoked.

```
function reality() {
    return function() {
        return function() {
            alert('in a Limbo');
        }
    };
}
```

Here `reality` is a function, `reality()` is a function, and `reality()()` is a function as well. However `reality()()()` is not a function, but simply `undefined` as we are not returning a function (we aren't returning anything) from the innermost function.

So for the `reality` function example, you could have passed any of the following to jQuery's bind.

```
$('#foo').bind('click', reality);
$('#foo').bind('click', reality());
$('#foo').bind('click', reality()());
```

Comment: Yay, I now hold the record for using "function" the most number of times out of all SO answers - 27.

Comment: +1 for Inception reference (and for good explanation, of course)

Comment: How about `var f = function(){ return f; }` as an example? Allows you to type `f()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()` _ad infinitum_, which is super cool.

Comment: @Avinash - it is not required to wrap each call inside parentheses.

Comment: Your talk is very informative and detailed and all information you have supplied is indeed correct, but I have to say that the actual answer to the question is wrong. I believe you missed the single quotes around 'monitor()' signifying that this is not a function or a function reference being called by a function (as with your inception example) but as the question suggests, it is a string that will be eval-ed later to be called as a function to be ran.

Answer (score 7):

Your jQuery `bind` example is similar to `setTimeout(monitor, 100);`, you are passing a reference of a function object as an argument.

Passing a string to the `setTimeout`/`setInterval` methods should be avoided for the same reasons you should avoid `eval` and the `Function` constructor when it is unnecessary.

The code passed as a string will be evaluated and run in the global execution context, which can give you "scope issues", consider the following example:

```
// a global function
var f = function () {
  alert('global');
};

(function () {
  // a local function
  var f = function() {
    alert('local');
  };

  setTimeout('f()', 100); // will alert "global"
  setTimeout(f, 100);     // will alert "local"
})();
```

The first `setTimeout` call in the above example, will execute the global `f` function, because the evaluated code has no access to the local lexical scope of the anonymous function.

If you pass the reference of a function object to the `setTimeout` method -like in the second `setTimeout` call- the exact same function you refer in the current scope will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing the same thing in your jQuery example as in the second `setTimeout` example - in your code you are passing the function and binding the `click` event.

In the first `setTimout` example, the `monitor` function is passed in and can be invoked directly, in the second, the sting `monitor()` is passed in and needs to be `eval`ed.

When passing a function around, you use the function name. When invoking it, you need to use the `()`.

Eval will invoke what is passed in, so a `()` is required for a successful function invocation.

Comment: So the comment is wrong? He should really be passing `setTimeout(monitor(), 100); //note the parens`?

Comment: @Isaac Lubow: No, the code is right--it's just that you're doing something different in each piece of code. The two examples are not the same.

Comment: If you want the `monitor` to execute after 100 ms, you would do `setTimeout(monitor(), 100); //note the parens?` then?

Comment: @Issac Lubow - `setTimeout(monitor(), 100);` will execute the `monitor` function immediately. `setTimeout("monitor()", 100);` will evaluate `monitor()` after 100 milliseconds. See the `"` in the second example?

Comment: @Isaac Lubow - All I meant is that simply having `monitor()` in the call to `setTimeout` (without the `"`) will call the function immediately, then the return value from it will get passed in to `setTimeout`.

Comment: I fiddled with it and yes, I get it. My confusion was due to something else in the code that was making it appear not to be executing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, "()" is not part of the function name.
It is syntax used to make function calls.

First, you bind a function to an identifier name by either using a function declaration:

```
function x() {
    return "blah";
}
```

... or by using a function expression:

```
var x = function() {
    return "blah";
};
```

Now, whenever you want to run this function, you use the parens:

```
x();
```

The setTimeout function accepts both and identifier to a function, or a string as the first argument...

```
setTimeout(x, 1000);
setTimeout("x()", 1000);
```

If you supply an identifier, then it will get called as a function.
If you supply an string, than it will be evaluated (executed).

The first method (supplying an identifier) is preferred ...

Comment: `If you supply an identifier, then it will get called as a function. If you supply an string, than it will be evaluated (executed).`
Can you explain the difference?

Comment: @Isaac If you supply a string, then this string will be executed as JavaScript code. For instance: `setTimeout('x = 3;', 100)`. As you can see, no function is called here. The string `'x = 3;'` is evaluated as an assignment expression. On the other hand, if you supply an identifier name, then this name must point to a function object (which will then be called).