# onclick function calling on its own

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, addeventlistener

I have a function:

```
beginFunction: function(){
//does stuff
}
```

that I call inside `componentDidMount(){this.beginFunction();}`

inside beginFunction I call a function with promises and inside the .then I call other functions.
one of the functions is this.retrieveMatches();
this.retrieveMatches(); calls another function `this.makeHTMLtable` and inside that function I have this line:
`msgButton.addEventListener("click", this.messageUser(), false);`

When I refresh the page, the code inside `this.messageUser(){console.log('hello')}` get runs before I click the button. How can I change my react code so that it only gets called on click (I though that is what an addEventListener would do??

Comment: `this.messageUser()` should be `this.messageUser`

Comment: And there are about 18 duplicates of this...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917666/addeventlistener-for-submit-event-runs-handler-function-early...

Comment: apologies for the duplicate lads and cheers @Rajesh for the answer!

Comment: but to be fair the duplicate marked at the top is slightly different to my question but granted @T.J.Crowder your link is exactly the same..