# jQuery on(); function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning Backbone and had some issues with the on()-function. But actually it's a very basic JavaScript question.

Why is it that the first line of code below works, and the second doesn't?
Using the second line, the render-function is never triggered. Mind the brackets.

**Works**

```
this.collection.on( 'reset', this.render, this );
```

**Fails**

```
this.collection.on( 'reset', this.render(), this );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "()" in a function call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641330/whats-the-meaning-of-in-a-function-call)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this.render()` executes function (so in your case you are passing data returned from this function), whereas `this.render` is handler to function.

Comment: so using this.render() it is only executed once, when I bind the function?

Comment: Yes, you are passing data returned by the `render()` function.