# Firefox: prevent (X)HTML paste in rich text editing

Tags: javascript, firefox, rich-text-editor

At some point Mozilla quietly added the ability to copy the actual (X)HTML code of a selection in Firefox to the clipboard instead of just the text content of the selection.

The question can be answered in a couple ways:

- Is there a poorly document execCommand that prevents paste from pasting anything other than text/plain?
- Is there a way to convert (X)HTML to text/plain during the paste event?

I am most interested in the Firefox HTML copy feature if it can be found.

I would rather not use a framework.

Comment: 1) Can you further explain "Mozilla queitly added the ability to copy the actual (X)HTML code of a selection" -- is this built-in, or you mean via an extension? 2) You can add [a listener for `paste` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onpaste) on your `input`/`textarea` but I haven't used that personally.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640187/how-can-i-modify-pasted-text

Comment: 1.) Text you copy in Firefox actually copies the (X)HTML code of the selection to the clipboard, not simply the textContent. 2.) That was a JavaScript question answered with jQuery.

Comment: Can't reproduce honestly (never happened to me). I've selected (CTRL-A) this page in Firefox 14, copied and pasted in the textarea below, or in Notepad, and it copies just text. Are you sure you don't have any add-ons that modify that? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, looks like I don't know the literature. This is related to `contentEditable`, right?

Comment: Yes, contentEditable / rich text editing.