# What does "event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData" mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text').match(/[^\d]/))
```

In the above code I don't understand the `originalEvent`, and `clipboardData` process. Please explain it to me briefly.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674963/event-originalevent-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640187/how-can-i-modify-pasted-text

Answer (score 4):

You have posted code that matches a string against a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (short: regex; a general pattern matching syntax). This string has been obtained through some objects and their properties/methods in response to a jquery event. In detail:

- [`event`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):
  a jquery event object.
- [`originalEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674963/event-originalevent-jquery):
  the underlying javascript event object.
- [`clipboardData`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html#widl-ClipboardEvent-clipboardData):
  this property reveals that the originalevent has been a [`ClipboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) (more specifically; a  [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) event) from the [ClipboardAPI](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html). The property returns a [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object that contains the typed data from the clipboard.
- [`getData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#getData.28.29):
  This method of the [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object extracts textual data from the clipboard contents.
- [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):
  This method retrieves all non-digits from the string as an array or returns null if the string contains digits only.

***Note***

Most of the links refer to the [MDN ( Mozilla Developer Network )](https://developer.mozilla.org), an excellent resource for web development. These pages usually contain links to the pertinent standards, most of which are accessible through the [w3c web site](http://w3c.org) too.

Consult these resources frequently and thoroughly, even if it takes time ! - they will vastly improve your development skills and actually save you time  in the long run!

I have no affiliations with MDN or W3C apart from using the infos and tools they offer.