# How to modify pasted data ? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

I followed this question [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)  to get the pasted data from the clipboard, but I used jquery instead. Now that I got the data, I removed all html tag. But I don't know how to paste it. 
`element` is a `contenteditable div`

```
element.on('paste', function (e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get pasted data via clipboard API
  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text').replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
  // How to paste pasteddata now?
  console.log(pastedData);
});
```

Comment: how to paste data where, to an input?

Comment: inside a contenteditable div

Comment: by the way you have a ; randomly in it

Comment: element.html(pastedData);

Comment: @andrew: this will replace element's html. Imo, the user who pastes some text in the middle of existing text doesn't expect all pre-existing text to get lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer and I am gonna share it. In order to sanitize the clipboard from html tags, you should paste this:

```
             element.on('paste', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var text;
                    var clp = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData;
                    if (clp === undefined || clp === null) {
                        text = window.clipboardData.getData("text") || "";
                        if (text !== "") {
                            text = text.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
                            if (window.getSelection) {
                                var newNode = document.createElement("span");
                                newNode.innerHTML = text;
                                window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(newNode);
                            } else {
                                document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(text);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        text = clp.getData('text/plain') || "";
                        if (text !== "") {
                            text = text.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
                            document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Credit: **l2aelba**

Comment: for IE11 seems you have to use `document.execCommand("paste", false, text)`

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me!
Please leave link to l2aelba's original comment

Comment: `execCommand` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Might be easier to let the paste proceed and update element immediately after. Would depend on use case also as cursor position could be lost this way

```js
$(':input').on('paste', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.val(function(){
            return this.value.replace(/foo/g, "bar"); 
        })
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>foo was here</p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, it depends on what element are you going to paste in. You could use jQuery or native Javascript to achieve!

Maybe like
`$(targetNode).append(pastedData)`
or
`document.getElementById('targetNode').innerText = pastedData`

Comment: paste can occur within existing content...this would wipe out other parts of that content or place pasted content at end where user isn't expecting it

Comment: @charlietfl have you got any other solution for not over writing existing content.