# Paste and Modify Content Pasted In Textarea - Showing Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the content that pastes in the Textarea, but facing a problem that it shows in the Textarea the original content and the "modified" content both.  Hope you can help me.

HTML Code (just a simple textarea):

```
<textarea name="Notes_999" class="cssDetail" id="Notes_999" autocomplete="off"> </textarea>
```

The Jquery code:

```
$(".cssDetail").bind("paste", function(e){
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var elemID = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("elemID: " + elemID);
    var t_string = "";
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    console.log("pastedData " + pastedData );
    var arrayOfLines = pastedData.split('\n');
    $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
        var cnt_spaces = item.search(/\S|$/);
        console.log("cnt_spaces: " + cnt_spaces + " - line: " + item);
        item = item.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        
        if (cnt_spaces == 8) {
            t_string +=  "- " + item + '\n';
        } else {
            t_string += item + '\n';
        }

    });
    
    //console.log("elemID: " + elemID);
    $("#"+elemID).text('');  // Try to clean before replace new content but not working.
    $("#"+elemID).text(t_string);
});
```

The function above works fine and does what I expected. However, the result inside the Textarea has both the original and the "modified " one (t_string variable).  I only want the "modified" one in the textarea, please help.

Thank you,

Comment: may be try `.val('')` here `$("#"+elemID).text('');`

Comment: I just tried that, but it is not working.  thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: cool, it would be easy if you could post related html and a small reproducible example.

Comment: I just updated the post with the HTML code (just a simple textarea). Thanks!

Comment: looks like its a timing issue. I tried setting timeout `setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + elemID).val(''); // Try to clean before replace new content but not working.
  }, 1000);` it cleared data after 1 sec. Unfortunately I not sure why this is an issue. but may be you could give it a try and find a work around.

Comment: Something similar is done here. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439018)

Comment: I tried that timing suggestion, it cleared data for both original and "modified" one.  weird.  Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: You need to do both clear and update with modified data in timeout function otherwise one will run before than other.

Comment: I tried that too, it will clear everything in 1 sec.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Actually, I followed the Link you suggested and it works.  Thank you very much!

Comment: awesome. glad it helped, cheers!